# No results from INNER JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

Hi I have a basic search function with two fields for the user to enter a test name and result type. I have tried a number of methods like using dropdowns as filters, but this is the most simple way I have found. I'm using INNER Joins on 3 tables in the search query. At moment no errors regarding the sql syntax are coming up but no results are echoing too. I ran the query on the database and it returned the results fine. Am I missing something stupid, any help would be much appreciated.

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) and $_GET['action'] =='search')
{

$resultts = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_GET['result'])));
$tests = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_GET['test'])));


if (isset($resultts) and ($tests))
{
$sql = "SELECT p.fileName, p.mimeType, p.dateCreated, t.testName, r.resultType
    FROM 'product_logs' AS p 
    INNER JOIN 'result' AS r 
    ON p.resultID=r.resultID
    INNER JOIN 'test' AS t
    ON r.testID=t.testID
    WHERE t.testName LIKE '%$tests%'
    AND r.resultType LIKE '%$resultts%'
    ORDER BY r.dateCreated DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die ("error in query");


}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>
<td>".$row['fileName']."</td>
<td>".$row['mimeType']."</td>
<td>".$row['dateCreated']."</td>
<td>".$row['testName']."</td>
<td>".$row['resultType']."</td>
</tr>";

}
}
```

The tables are

```
result

resultID    int(6)  NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
resultType  varchar(15) NO      NULL    
resultDate  date    NO      NULL    
testID   int(11)    NO  MUL NULL    
testerID    int(11) NO  MUL NULL    
productID   int(11) NO  MUL NULL    

product_logs

logID       int(5)      NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
mimeType    varchar(50) NO      NULL    
fileData    mediumblob  NO      NULL    
fileName    varchar(255)NO      NULL    
dateCreated date        NO      NULL    
resultID    int(11)    YES  MUL NULL

test

testID    int(5)        NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
testName varchar(10)    NO      NULL    
testDate date           NO      NULL
```

Here is the form Im using

```
echo "<form action= results_page.php method= get>";
echo"<p>Search Product Logs:</p>";

echo"<div>";
echo"<label for=text>Please Enter Test Name:</label>";
echo"<input type=text name=test id=text/>";
echo"<label for=text>Please Enter Result Type:</lable>";
echo"<input type=text name=result id=text/>";
echo"<input type=hidden name=action value=search/>";
echo"<input type=submit value=Search>";
echo"</div>";
echo"</form>";
```

Comment: can you dump the php generated query to the screen. not the results, but the actual query it's sending to the server.

Comment: Erm forgive me I'm a bit of a newbie, how do you do that?

Comment: `$resultts` and `$tests` in `LIKE` constructs are missing trailing `s`

Comment: Ive just changed the variables in the LIKE construct still no results echoing out.

Comment: You used 3 tables in the SQL statement, `product_logs`, `result`, and `test` - but you only listed 2 tables, neither of which you named.  Could you list all three tables, and label them so we know which table is which?

Comment: Is there any qualifying data to be returned? Have you tried running the query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Hi I have just labelled and added the third table. Yes I ran the query in phpMyAdmin before i wrote the script and it returned the required results

Comment: can you do `var_dump($resultts)` and `var_dump($test)` or do `echo $sql; ` before you do mysqli_query so we can see the query and variables

Comment: Ive just var_dump both variables and echo($sql) nothing is being echoed out

Comment: I fixed the problem. It was an issue with the form. Thank you guys for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You test if `$resultts` and `$tests` exist, but then you use `$resultt` and `$test` in the sql statement itself.  Additionally, you are testing on the value of `$tests`, not whether or not it's set.  Try this instead:

```
if (isset($resultts) and isset($tests))
{
    $sql = "SELECT p.fileName, p.mimeType, p.dateCreated, t.testName, r.resultType
        FROM 'product_logs' AS p 
        INNER JOIN 'result' AS r 
        ON p.resultID=r.resultID
        INNER JOIN 'test' AS t
        ON r.testID=t.testID
        WHERE t.testName LIKE '%$tests%'
        AND r.resultType LIKE '%$resultts%'
        ORDER BY r.dateCreated DESC";

    $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die ("error in query");
}else{
    // Insert error type message or handling here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I've modified the variables in the sql but still no results are echoed out.

Comment: Just realized that you're also testing on the value of $tests, not on whether or not it's set.  Modified the code in the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Just tried it, but no results still. Its got me stumped.

Comment: But is it going into the 'if' section or the 'else' section there?

Comment: at the moment there is no else section for error handling just wanted to make sure the sql was correct first

Comment: And if the error isn't in the SQL but is actually somewhere else, you'll keep wasting your time looking at the SQL.  Put in that error handling first - that's what the error handling is FOR.  Telling you exactly where and what the problem is.  I'm pretty sure you're never actually calling that SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I done what you said and $resultts and $tests are not defined and there is no string being parsed to the $_GET.

Comment: Well, that goes outside of the data you've provided for the question.  There's all sorts of reasons that could be.

Comment: Ill have a deeper look it's quite strange as it is only string entered by a user into text fields. Ok thank you for your time and help it has been much appreciated, least I know where I've got the problem.

Comment: Well, that might be the problem.  Usually, `$_GET` data is entered via the URL string, while form data (ie: text fields) gets put into `$_POST`